# ElasticSearch fields prefixed with "@"

Tags: elasticsearch

I see a lot of fields in example mappings that look like `@timestamp`, `@name`, etc.

What does it mean? Does it make any change or is it some convention?
It is tricky to google and I didn't find any reference reading the doc.

Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/deverton/2970285

```
        ...
        "properties" : {
            "@fields": { "type": "object", "dynamic": true, "path": "full" }, 
            "@message" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed" },
            "@source" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "@source_host" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "@source_path" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "@tags": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }, 
            "@timestamp" : { "type" : "date", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "@type" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
        }
        ...
```

Comment: afaik, it doesnot change anything.

Comment: can you give a link to one such example mapping?

Comment: here's an example from logstash's code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those settings do not affect anything. They are standardised logstash fields which are used so you can easily report on logs originating from multiple sources.

They are just a logstash convention and not an elasticsearch convention.